# splitting a line on a multi character delimiter using pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

I am running the following simple program:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String valid = "abc|~abc|~abc|~abc|~abc|~|~|~|~|~|~|~abc";
        String invalid = "xyz|~xyz|~xyz|~xyz|~xyz|~|~|~|~|~|~|~";
        String delimiter = "|~";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
        String[] tokensValid = pattern.split(valid);
        String[] tokensInvalid = pattern.split(invalid);
        System.out.println("Valid: " + tokensValid.length);
        System.out.println("InValid: " + tokensInvalid.length);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Valid: 12
InValid: 5
```

But I feel the output should be:

```
Valid: 12
InValid: 12
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [one-arg overload of `String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) will discard all empty trailing empty tokens.

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

You have 7 of them.  That's why you get `5` for your "InValid" case.

To get `12`, you must use the [two-arg overload of `String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), with a negative limit (or a limit of at least `12`), which doesn't discard trailing empty tokens.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

From [`split` method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split-java.lang.CharSequence-) (emphasis mine)

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given input sequence and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

In other words splitting `"xyz|~xyz|~xyz|~xyz|~xyz|~|~|~|~|~|~|~"` on `|~` will at start produce array

```
["xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz","","","","","","",""]
```

but because `limit` parameter in invoked internally [`split(CharSequence input, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split-java.lang.CharSequence-int-) method was set to `0` trailing empty strings ware removed, which means result array you got was

```
["xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz"]
```

which is length 5.

Based on documentation of these method if you want to avoid removing trailing empty strings you can use this method with negative `limit` value like

```
String[] tokensInvalid = pattern.split(invalid, -1);
//                                              ^^^
```